# Pipenv issues when running cron job

Tags: linux, cron, pipenv

I have a cron job to download files by the minute:

[ec2-user]$ crontab -l
`* * * * * /var/xxy/xy/xyy/run.sh`

The contents of run.sh are:
`/usr/local/bin/pipenv run start -i config.ini --json /var/xxy/xy/xyy/output-logs/json`

The files download fine when running `run.sh` manually by invoking a simple `sh run.sh`

The cron job never runs and i have this error in the var/log/cron:

```
[ec2-user@ip-x.x.x.x xyy]$ sudo tail -2 /var/log/cron
Jan 23 13:57:01 ip-x.x.x.x CROND[30428]: (ec2-user) CMD (var/xxy/xy/xyy/run.sh)
Jan 23 13:57:02 ip-x.x.x.x CROND[30426]: (ec2-user) CMDOUT (Error: the command start could not be found within PATH or Pipfile's [scripts].)
```

The Pipfile definitely has the command `start` in it; because it works when i manually invoke the run script.

Does the cron job pull files from somewhere else and I need to update the Pipfile script there too??

I'm using an Oracle Linux server hosted in AWS.

Sincerely yours,
Very Confused

Comment: `pipenv` rlies on being run from the appropriate directory (one containing your Pipfile, or a child of that directory). You'll need to modify `run.sh` to change to the appropriate directory first.

Comment: verified that my "run.sh" is in the same directory where my Pipfile is. Also confirming that my Pipfile has the command "start" pointing to my project. When i run "sh run.sh" it runs fine, but the cronjob wont work for some reason

Comment: This isn't about where your `run.sh` is located; it's about your current working directory when running the `pipenv` command.

Comment: I was able to get this issue fixed by adding my PATH (found by issuing a printenv) in the crontab job itself, and specifying which SHELL the cron job should use (in my case it was SHELL=/bin/bash)